# Почему при создании токена jwt возникает ошибка - Unsupported media type?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

Отправляю через postman запрос на /api/auth/token/create/. В body указываю username и password. В headers установлен Content-Type:application/json и Accept:application/json.

В ответ получаю:

> {"detail": "Unsupported media type \"multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------286954501919688601950776\" in request."}

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('admin', admin.site.urls)]
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.gis',
'rest_framework',
"rest_framework.authtoken",
'djoser',
'corsheaders',]

MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
#'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
            'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
                    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'),
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (# 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',)
}
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

[Установленные пакеты](https://pastebin.com/wzyX58UE)(сделал через pastebin потому, что много места здесь занимает)

Еще очень странная ошибка возникает, если удалить пакет "djangorestframework-simplejwt". 
При запуске сервера, здесь:

```
path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
```

возникает ошибка:

> No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'

хотя я использую "rest_framework_jwt", а не "rest_framework_simplejwt".

Ну а после установки simplejwt ошибки на сервере не возникает, но и токен не могу создать.

Comment: Покажите код отправки запроса. А то вы пишите "В headers установлен Content-Type:application/json", а сервер пишет "media type multipart/form-data".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не совсем понимаю какой код. [Это](https://imgur.com/a/usJLem8)?

Comment: Ааа, вы через postman отправляете. Не обратил внимания. Проверяйте настройки, сервере приходит не тот Content-Type.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev какие настройки? настройки django или postman? В postman все правильно вроде.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev разобрался. Написал body не в form-data, а в raw(json) и все заработало. Спасибо. Странно, все по гайду делаю. А не знаете почему django требует rest_framework_simplejwt, когда я использую rest_framework_jwt?

Comment: Нет, этого не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал данные не в form-data, а в raw(json формате) и все заработало.